# I am wondering why I cannot override jquery function onRegionOver. The WAMP index.html file is shown below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering why I cannot override jquery function onRegionOver. The WAMP index.html file is shown below. Please tell me how I can use the WAMP console to debug this problem.
The jquery plugin I am trying to make work on my Windows 7 Internet Explorer IE7 browser here is http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.css"
type="text/css" media="screen"/>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="us-aea-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="USA-map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px"></div>
  <script language="javascript">
    function processOrder() {
     var pluginContainer = $("#USA-map");
         pluginContainer.vectorMap(
           {map: 'us_aea_en'},

           {onRegionOver: function(event, code){
                   alert('Hello');
           }
         });
  }
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.vectorMap()` function accepts a single object with multiple parameters, while you're passing 2.

Presumably the call should look like:

```
    pluginContainer.vectorMap(
       {
           map: 'us_aea_en',
           onRegionOver: function(event, code){
               alert('Hello');
           }
       }
     );
```

References:

- http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/
- http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/

Comment: I just tested your answer and it works with WAMP2.4_x86.

Comment: @Frank: it's javascript it works on a client - so it *doesn't matter* what is installed on the server.

Comment: @@zerkms;Please explain why your code is javascript  instead of jquery

Comment: ;Please explain why your code is javascript instead of jquery

Comment: @Frank: are you sure you understand what terms `javascript` and `jquery` mean? Asking it because your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: ;I understand what the terms javascript and jquery mean. Could you please look at some vectormap code?

Comment: @@zerkmsI understand what the terms javascript and jquery mean. Could you please look at some vectormap code?

Comment: @Frank: that's what stackoverflow is for. If you have another question - just ask another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44475/discussion-between-frank-and-zerkms)

Comment: @@zerkmes; I solved the problem The HTML regions USA-map and container overlap. I removed the HTML region container. Thanks for all of your help help this evening. I am going to sleep now.